# Making a member function a friend

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

What happens when you make a member function of a class a friend of itself!?

The code below compiles and runs. Without the friend declaration a 'too many arguments to operator' is generated (and rightly so). I realise that doing this doesn't make any sense but can anyone tell me what is happening here? Does friend force the compiler to omit the default this parameter in some way?

```
class Test
{
public:
  friend bool operator<(Test& lhs, Test& rhs)
  {
     return true;
  }
};

int main( int c, char** argv)
{
  Test test1;
  Test test2;

  return test1 < test2;
}
```

Comment: To answer your question: Friends cannot be members of the befriending class in C++03, but such is allowed in C++0x.

Comment: i'm curious, what possible point could there be for allowing a member function to be a friend of itself since it already has complete access?

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#77 or the history (that particular case isn't of much importance though, because nested classes have full access to the nesting class in c++0x and most c++03 compilers anyway).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that a friend is not a member even if the entire definition appears inside the class; rather, the function is placed in the surrounding namespace.  So, there is no `this` pointer.  While a member `operator<` operates implicitly on `this` and the explicit right-hand-side argument, a `friend` needs both left- and right-hand side argument provided explicitly as function parameters - hence the extra parameter.  Your `friend` version is equivalent to putting the function after the class, except that it has access to the `private` and `protected` members and bases and is implicitly `inline` (though that doesn't mean the compiler has to inline it - it's only a hint, but it's important with respect to the One Definition Rule in that your `friend` function can be included from many translation units and link without issues).

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when you make a member function of a class a friend of itself!?

That doesn't make any sense. How can a *member function* of a class be a *friend* of the same class?

You have overloaded `operator <` as a friend function (not as a member function). Providing the definition(body) of a friend function inside the class is legal. However it is illegal to use `this` inside its definition

```
friend bool operator<(Test& lhs, Test& rhs)
{
     *this ; //error
     return true;
}
```